# TypeError: an integer is required in Python Spacy-Stopword NLP

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

why getting error like "Integer is Required" in Python Spacy???

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
doc = nlp('Hello World')
for word in doc:
    print(nlp.vocab[word].is_stop)
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-028ad9619aba> in <module>()
      5 doc = nlp('Hello World')
      6 for word in doc:
----> 7     print(word in nlp.vocab)

vocab.pyx in spacy.vocab.Vocab.__contains__()

TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: what do you want as your out put, do you want the output as true/false or something else

Comment: yes, tries to print true, false based on stopwords

Comment: "Based on stopwords" ? But you're checking if the word exists in `nlp.vocab`, shouldn´t you replace the checking like this `print(word in STOP_WORDS) ` ? Because `vocab` returns the lexemes

Comment: i dont think print(word in STOP_WORDS) will work, we have to check like print(nlp.vocab['via'].is_stop), wants to check token is stopword or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
doc = nlp('Hello World')
for word in doc:
    print(str(word) in STOP_WORDS)
```

Use this if you need it for stopwords

Answer (score 1):

simply converted token into string and it works

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
doc = nlp('Hello World, I am Juned')
for word in doc:
    print(nlp.vocab[str(word)].is_stop)
```

Answer (score 1):

The stop word value is available as a `Token` attribute on the tokens in the `Doc`, so this can be simplified to:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
doc = nlp('Hello World')
for word in doc:
    print(word.is_stop)
```